# why do I find registry problems and unnecessary files after Windows 10 reset and might they cause further problems?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, reset, cleaning, disk-cleanup

My laptop has two drives inside: an SSD where I put the operative systems (WIndows 10 x64 and Linux in dual boot) and a hard disk which I use for media storage and installing most of softwares.

I did the Windows 10 reset and re-installation by choosing the options which let me deleting all personal data and files in the drive where Windows was installed (the SSD) without affecting the other drives.

Windows was reset and installed again on my pc and as soon as everything finished I launched some cleaning tools (which are portable and stored in the second hard disk, so I can use them without a new installation) and the reports say I have both many problems in the registry and some files to delete, as you can see in the screens below ->

[image: errori]

[image: errori registro]

I didn't delete them yet, so I can check for further information if needed for diagnosis.

My laptop didn't come with Windows 10 preinstalled and the first time I installed it I used a ISO from usb (I downloaded it from Microsoft website and I activated it with a license I bought on ebay); everything worked well, although I didn't run any diagnostic tool then and I cannot say if I had useless files and registry keys.
This time Windows reinstalled itself automatically without asking me any license or ISO.

My question is:

Why a Windows 10 operative system which is supposed to be clean for having been reset and reinstalled on the same drive comes with errors in the registry and useless files and data?
Might it cause any conflict while reinstalling my softwares on the "new" operative system?

Comment: This just sounds like residual material found by the software that technically isn't necessary and may very well be left over after the installation process.

Comment: might It cause any trouble while installing my softwares again on the new windows (I added on the Q now)? Or should I opte for a standard reset and installation from ISO file on usb stick to avoid any problem in the future?

Comment: It shouldn't cause any problems. Regardless, I'm more likely to trust the CCleaner than the other utilities; using CCleaner to remove the extraneous files shouldn't cause any harm (I do this regularly and have not had any trouble). I can't necessarily trust the other programs; some may clean too aggressively and cause problems.

Comment: me too but I use more than one, for sure

Comment: The registry is designed to have stuff added to it.  Those "missing shared dlls", can exist and they no impact, on system performance.  "Why a Windows 10 operative system which is supposed to be clean for having been reset and reinstalled on the same drive comes with errors in the registry and useless files and data?" - I would assume because you missinterrupted what actually happen and Windows wasn't reinstalled.  In other words, doing a Windows 10 Reset won't wipe your registry, only doing a Refresh would have resulted in that.

Comment: I urge you not to use "Registry Repair", "CCleaner", or "Glary Utilities" and to clean your registry.  Using these programs to clean your registry will cause more harm then good.

Comment: @Ramhound is exactly right.  There is *very* little potential benefit from utilizing a registry cleaning utility, and it could cause some rather significant problems.

Comment: Me I often install and uninstall several programs, should I keep all their registry left over information in the registry? and what about regscanner?

Comment: @Ramhound what about revo uninstaller?

Comment: It does exactly what Add/Remove Programs does?

Answer (score 1):

Few tips for the CCleaner-user.

1) please exclude those and dont let the ccleaner correct them - this might cause problems for your registry and huge amount of gray hairs

2) thats a long and well-known issue on the CCleaner, since it doesnt quite read the content_type correctly (if at all) - i strongly suggest only to clean something else, but the registry with this software